# How to add a "Suggest Our FaceBook Page to A Friend" interface on a website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With the many programming tools from FaceBook, like FaceBook connect, graph api, etc...

**Is there a way to create a form on a website that does this:**

I. Website visitor logs into FaceBook (from my website)

II. Form changes. Website visitor is presented with button:

**"*Invite FaceBook Friends to Like Our FaceBook Page*"**

III. Form changes to new interface. User is able to view his friends, choose specific friends and suggest FaceBook page to them. User clicks submit button.

IV.  FaceBook page is suggested to friends. Data is sent to custom website application/DB to track the FaceBook info of the person who made the suggestion(s).

The whole point of this is that we want to offer a people who refer their FaceBook friends to our FaceBook page some sort of incentive (free product) and we need a way to encourage & track that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to this for login with Facebook and knowing whether the user is connected or not: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login

To present the user with an "invite friends" type of interface refer to http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector

You will notice that the `<fb:request-form/>` tag takes a content attribute that contains a `<fb:req-choice/>` tag. This tag contains the url where people accepting the invitation will be directed. You can use this url to refer the person who sent the invitation. By adding a query parameter with it's Facebook id for example.